# Minecraft Closes Randomly with a Java Exception

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Unlike when the game crashes it goes to a black screen and then the stack trace. This time the game just closes and leaves a nice hs_err_pid.txt file for us, which you can find [here](http://pastebin.com/XxDQuf1x).

I've checked around Google and most people's answer is to Update my Graphics card, I have attempted this and the AMD Auto Detect application just tells me that it's up to date.

**System:**
I record with Fraps sometimes but this does not mean that this causes it (it happens when not recording too). I also run Minecraft on a RAMDisk that has 512MB.

Can anyone give me any advice about this?

Comment: Do you also save your world to that RAMDisk?  I'm wondering if there's a space issue, and Minecraft can't save your world.

Comment: "# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows" Seems that there is not enough space on that disk. Did you try to launch it directly with the JAR ? (with cmd and java command ?)

Comment: Minecraft takes up about 300MB out of the 500MB, I've actually removed it from the RAMDisk to see if it was that. Like what "user25278" said I uninstalled Java 7 and installed Java 6 (update 25).

However even after doing this it is still closing and now it's not even giving a hs_err_pid.txt for me to look at.

Comment: Do you get this error if you run Minecraft with Java 6? There are all kinds of reports that Java 7 and Minecraft hate each other.

Comment: This randomly started happening to my little sisters laptop...

Comment: @Nick122 does your little sister have a RAMDisk setup?

Comment: @Qix Nope, not at all. It seemed to have fixed itself, however. I forced update updated java a few times. It finally just started working again. Odd.

Comment: It could have easily been on Minecraft's end. They could have pushed out a semi-buggy release.

Comment: The problem posed by this question does not specifically depend on mods being installed. The cause is different: (Java is not up to date). It has useful, helpful answers and is resolved. Please don't retroactively close already solved problems, especially when the answer is used as a reference many times. The 'minecraft mod' close reason is for when we are unable to answer a question, which is not this situation.

Comment: @aphid, I agree completely with your reasoning, but to clarify: the 'modded Minecraft' closing reason is **not** there for when we're unable to answer a question, but because - among other things - it is hard if not impossible to reproduce a posed problem (see also [this answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10391/222022)).

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your error dump file, there are several things that catch my eye.

Line 298 shows you're running `Minecraft.exe` instead of the JAR file. While normally this isn't an issue, I've seen weird stuff with the EXE as opposed to the jar. **Try running with just the [minecraft JAR](https://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftDownload/launcher/minecraft.jar)** instead to see if it works. You could also **try force updating** (in the launcher, click "Options" and then check "Force Update"; login) to see if that helps anything.

On line 75 it specifies that there is an error with a GL (lwjgl) call to `nglCallList` (or `glCallList`) which suggests a drivers issue. Keep in mind lwjgl uses native libraries to do what it does (more or less parts of the program that aren't completely Java and depend almost entirely on the specific operating system you're running) so it's not necessarily Java's fault.

As others have suggested, **make sure your drivers are up to date** (`GL11` in LWJGL means OpenGL 1.1 - if your graphics card doesn't support it, you're going to definitely need a new graphics card...). You're running on Windows 7x64 with an ATI card so [updating](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx), if necessary, shouldn't be a problem.

Furthermore, I saw line 138, which shows you have at least one mod installed; **try disabling/removing mods completely**, as they are notorious for screwing things up.

**Make sure your MSVC runtimes are updated** (at the very least make sure [08](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29)/[10](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555)/[12](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9815734)'s x86 versions are up to date - yes, you're on 64-bit but the JNL libraries Minecraft uses are 32-bit).

And, as always, **make sure your Java is up to date** (your dump log suggests you're just a little bit behind - about 5-6 builds).

If none of that fixes the issue, then it could very well be a RAMDisk issue as many have suggested in the original post's comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a known problem with the LJWGL library in 64 bits system, Windows and Linux OS are alike.
Follow [this tutorial](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Update_LWJGL)

.
Also **backup** first your dlls and jar files, then try to replace them with the newset version of LJWGL.
If this doesn't work, try do downgrade to openjdk 6.

Comment: I've actually already manually upgraded the LJWGL. I was thinking of maybe downgrading the Java version as people seem to say that 7 isn't all that great. I will try that!

Comment: No sense in backing up the Driver DLLs if they aren't working. Also, Java7 works fine; downgrading won't fix anything, and may end up breaking even more things.

Comment: LJWGL dlls, not driver dlls*

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your drivers are wrong or you have two types of drivers installed. If you have Intel hardware like I have you have to get rid of your AMD drivers.

I searched for [Driversweeper](http://www.guru3d.com/content_page/guru3d_driver_sweeper.html) and downloaded that to delete my AMD video card drivers, and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your .minecraft/bin folder and delete openal64 (if you're running a 64 bit OS) or openal32 (if you're using a 32 bit OS).

openal is the sound file for Minecraft, so you wont have any sound but it wont crash.

Comment: I would downvote if I had enough rep; this has nothing to do with OpenAL. At all.

Answer (score -1):

This is very easy to fix.

If you don't have any world to save, just delete your .minecraft.
If you have any worlds to save, copy them to an empty folder and then delete the .minecraft folder.
If you Cant delete the minecraft folder, then go to taskmanager and find javaw.exe click end task and try deleting the .minecraft folder again.

#### How to find .minecraft

1. Click the Windows logo in the left corner of the screen
2. Type in "run"
3. Type in `%appdata%`

#### How to find taskmanager

1. Click ctrl+alt+delete
2. Click taskmanager.

Comment: why do my answer get down votes?? write why you thing its bad!

Comment: Killing `java.exe` doesn't delete your .minecraft folder.

Comment: @JeffreyLin If, however, the `.minecraft` folder can't be deleted because a Minecraft process is still running, then killing `java.exe` can unlock the folder.

Comment: This doesn't explain how it fixes the problem.

Comment: @Yves Well, then, he should have clarified, since I (and probably others as well) thought that he meant killing java.exe would kill the folder.

Comment: `java.exe` isn't Minecraft (directly). It could be anything. Also, for the most part, it's `javaw.exe` that is the final EXE getting run for Minecraft, not `java.exe`.